# how to get the id of parent by clicking child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the id of parent div when clicking child but can't find any logic to do that. Let take the following example:-

```
<div class="something" id="mainParentDiv">
    <div class = "childClass" id = "parent1">
       <div id = "child1" class = "smallestChild">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the id "parent1" by clicking "smallestChild"? I'm new in JQuery so sorry if this question is so naïve or basic. I am really unable to find solution for this. There are other questions but they are asking for getting child's id by clicking parent. Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you want the immediate parent, it'd be `$(this).parent().attr("id")` (where `this` is the #child1 element).

Comment: Since click events bubble, you should most likely be able to attach your click handler to `#parent1` to begin with to achieve the desired outcome (unknown) without an extra step ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```js
$('.smallestChild').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().attr('id');
  console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" id="mainParentDiv">
    <div class = "childClass" id = "parent1">
       <div id = "child1" class = "smallestChild">Button
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```